# How to open jackcess database in java from remote location without downloading the file as a file object

Tags: java, database, io, server

```
Database database = Database.open(new File("http://example.com/filename.mdb"));
```

when I hit this url it downloads the file and when I try to read the file in java code it shows an error

> file does not exist